# Undefined reference when linking to .a library

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking

I'm trying out this library:

https://github.com/dacap/clip

I've git-cloned it, then built it using the following:

```
cmake .
make
```

This produces a library called `libclip.a`.

Now, I've taken the sample Hello World code, which is this:

```
#include "clip/clip.h"

int main() {
  clip::set_text("Hello World");
}
```

Given that the above is in a file called *cliptest2.cpp*, I compile it as follows:

```
g++ -lclip cliptest2.cpp -o cliptest2
```

Every time, I get the following:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc71SQmy.o: in function `main':
> cliptest2.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `clip::set_text(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I do understand how the linker works and have gone through dozens of other questions with similar errors. However, given that I am building the third party library and linking it into my sample program, I don't understand why the `set_text()` method is not being resolved.

**Edit**: I've tried a few things, also as a result of the comments below. The source code for the clip library resides at `~/git/clip`, and I am compiling cliptest2.cpp from the home directory itself. Therefore, adjusting  the command suggested by @MathiasSchmid to my environment, I end up with this:

```
g++ cliptest2.cpp -I git -L git/clip -lclip -lxcb -lpthread -o cliptest2
```

I run this on my Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, and get all the following errors:

```
daniel@orion:~$ g++ cliptest2.cpp -I git -L git/clip -lclip -lxcb -lpthread -o cliptest2   
/usr/bin/ld: git/clip/libclip.a(clip_x11.cpp.o): in function `clip::x11::write_data_fn(png_struct_def*, unsigned char*, unsigned long)':
clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
/usr/bin/ld: git/clip/libclip.a(clip_x11.cpp.o): in function `clip::x11::write_png(clip::image const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&)':
clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x232): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `png_write_info'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x255): undefined reference to `png_set_packing'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x27a): undefined reference to `png_malloc'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x3cd): undefined reference to `png_write_rows'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x3e9): undefined reference to `png_free'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x3fc): undefined reference to `png_write_end'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x40f): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: git/clip/libclip.a(clip_x11.cpp.o): in function `clip::x11::read_data_fn(png_struct_def*, unsigned char*, unsigned long)':
clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x45d): undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
/usr/bin/ld: git/clip/libclip.a(clip_x11.cpp.o): in function `clip::x11::read_png(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, clip::image*, clip::image_spec*)':
clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x575): undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x5a1): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x5cd): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x5f5): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x628): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x68f): undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x6a8): undefined reference to `png_read_info'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x6ea): undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x747): undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x8bf): undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x8ce): undefined reference to `png_set_packing'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x8dd): undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x8ec): undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x8fb): undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x90a): undefined reference to `png_set_tRNS_to_alpha'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x919): undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x938): undefined reference to `png_read_update_info'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x95a): undefined reference to `png_malloc'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0x9ab): undefined reference to `png_malloc'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0xa19): undefined reference to `png_read_rows'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0xbe0): undefined reference to `png_free'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0xc05): undefined reference to `png_free'
/usr/bin/ld: clip_x11.cpp:(.text+0xc4b): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is still not clear to me what the problem here is.

Comment: Where is `libclip.a` ?

Comment: Does `nm` show `clip::set_text` method in _libclip.a_?

Comment: Move source file in front of library on compile command line and add missing libraries. I also had to add the path to `libclip.a` location using '-L` option. The following call works for your example on my machine running Ubuntu 20.04. `g++ cliptest2.cpp -L. -lclip -lxcb -lpthread -o cliptest2`

Comment: The order in which you give files to the linker matters. References from earlier files are searched for in later files but not the other way around. So the order of the two files in your command line is wrong.

Comment: I defined them in this order because specifying the cpp file before the library (as suggested) produces a long list of errors instead of just one. Also, @MathiasSchmid what made you determine you needed those other libraries?

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk apparently not (I tried `nm git/clip/libclip.a | grep clip::set_text`)

Comment: Not `clip::set_text`, try mangled symbol to ensure your compiled clip with this method.

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk what do you mean by mangled symbol?

Comment: Take a look at http://web.mit.edu/tibbetts/Public/inside-c/www/mangling.html

Comment: @Gigi I used the command line of your example, moved the source file to the right position, saw the long list of errors you mentioned, read the content of the error messages and came to the result that `libclip.a` depends on `libxcb` and `libpthread`. Note: This dependency to `libxcb` and `libpthread` is valid for target system i used (Linux) and is also listed at `CMakeLists.txt` of `libclip`.

Comment: @MathiasSchmid thanks, I suppose my errors were different from yours as there was no mention of the other libraries in the output. I've updated the question and provided more info on the exact command I ran (based on yours) and the corresponding output. I'm still quite confused, to be honest.

Comment: @Gigi If you take a look at `CMakeLists.txt` of `libclip` there is build variant using `libpng` instead of `libxcb` depending on some settings on build machine. The error messages you added to your question show undefined references to `libpng` functions.

Comment: @Gigi Correction to my last comment: There is a variant using `libxcb` and `libpng`. Sorry.

Comment: @MathiasSchmid you're the man. This did it: `g++ cliptest2.cpp -I git -L git/clip -lclip -lxcb -lpng -lpthread -o cliptest2`. Thanks so much.